# Display ad image after every nth row in jquery datatable using colspan

Tags: jquery, datatable

My datatable has 100 rows with page length set to 10. I want to display an ad image dynamically after every 6th row. This advt position should not be affected by the sort order / pagination.

```
    <table id="example">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Subject</th>
             <th>By</th>
             <th>Location</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>3</td>
          </tr>

// if row index = 6 then show advt image by merging columns. I gather colspan is not supported.

          <tr>
             <td colspan="3">show advt</td>
             <td style="display: none;"></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

Adding colspan results in loosing the sort and pagination functionality. The below hack also doesn't work.

```
<td style="display: none;"></td>
```

If I add child row at 6th; it is lost at the time of sorting.

Comment: This could help provided I am able to pass the index value to c# https://datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html

Answer (score 0):

You can select every 6th, 12th, 18th row by searching for `tr:nth-child(6n)`.

You can use jQuery's [`after()`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) to insert content. Together you'd use it as follows:

```
$('tr:nth-child(6n)').after('<div>ad</div>');
```

Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/zoa5fkga/

I'm not sure how this would affect your pagination, but maybe you can tweak your pagination's settings to accommodate the ad, or only to initialise pagination after the ads have been inserted?

Comment: how is this supposed to work in datatable plugin? Op already mentioned sorting issues

Comment: Ah… I was unaware datatable was a plugin, I just thought it'd be a `table` showing results from a database!

Comment: Can be done this way but would need to be in rendering callbacks exposed by plugin